# Как определить, активна ли страница в браузере?

Tags: webkit, javascript, webbrowser

Доброго времени суток.
Возможно ли определить активна ли страница в браузере? 
Другими словами, если я в браузере открываю другую закладку или открываю другое приложение, затем возвращаюсь к браузеру с нужной мне страницей, возникает ли какое-нибудь событие в окне, которое можно отловить? Если конкретнее, то мне надо обновлять кое-какую информацию после того как страница в браузере снова стала активной в окне. Мне надо только для движка `webkit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [How do I detect if the browser window is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841671/how-do-i-detect-if-the-browser-window-is-active)
- [How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)